# Autonomous Vehicle Sharing Reservation problem CPLEX code correction

Tags: cplex

I am trying to crack a CPLEX code for this paper about reserving shared autonomous vehicle. First, I did not use a tuple for this, but later I realized that I need to. So I tried to combine the tuple into the vehicle routing problem, but CPLEX does not give me a solution. The attached images are the parameters, objective function, and constraints for the paper, followed by my code.

[image: parameter]
[image: objectivefunction+constraints]

---

```
int n = 5;
range N = 1..n;
int F =3;
range car=1..F;

tuple Arc{
 int fromNode; //1 - 5
 int toNode;  // 1 - 5
 float dist;  //1-8 
 int fromTime; //1-4
 int toTime; // 1 - 5
 int TTime // 1 -3
}

range I=1..5;
range J=1..5;
range L=1..8;
range M=1..4;
range O=1..5;
range P=1..3;


{Arc} Arcs = {<1,4,4,1,2,1>,<2,1,1,1,3,2>,<2,3,1.5,3,4,1>, <2,4,1,2,4,2>,<3,2,7,2,5,3>,<3,4,3,1,3,2>,<3,5,1,1,2,1>,<4,1,2,3,4,1>,<5,2,1,2,3,1>,<5,3,2,4,5,1>,<5,4,5,2,4,2>};
int m[I][J];  
dvar boolean x[I][J];
dvar int u[2..n];

minimize sum (i in I, j in J,a in Arcs) a.dist*x[i][j];

subject to{

    forall(i in I,j in N)
        sum (a in Arcs : a.toNode == i) x[i][j] == sum (a in Arcs : a.fromNode == i) x[i][j]; 


    forall (i in N, j in J)
        sum (a in Arcs : a.toNode == i) x[i][j] == 1;

    forall(a in Arcs : a.toNode>1 && a.fromNode>1, i in N, j in J)
        u[a.toNode] +1 <= u[a.fromNode] + 1000*(1-x[i][j]);


    forall (a, b in Arcs, i in N, j in N)
        if (a.toTime - b.fromTime<0) x[i][j]==0;
    forall (a in Arcs, i in N, j in N)
        sum (a in Arcs) x[i][j] <=F;
    forall (a in Arcs, i in N, j in N)
        x[i][j]<=m[i][j];
    forall (i,j in N)
        sum(j in N) x[i][j] == sum(j in N) x[j][i];
    forall (i,j in N)
        if (i==1 && j==5) m[i][j]==F;
        else m[i][j]==1;
    forall (i,j in N:j!=1)
        if (i==1) x[i][j]==F;
    forall (i,j in N:j!=5)
        if (i==5) x[j][i]==F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

several issues in your model:

1. int m[I][J]; means that all m will be 0 which looks strange
2. F is 3 and x is boolean so the following looks quite strange too

   forall (i,j in N:j!=1) if (i==1) x[i][j]==F;

   forall (i,j in N:j!=5)if (i==5) x[j][i]==F;